# Usage of "While in"

Tags: conjunctions

I have found a sentence on Google.
"While in Bangkok, you should go to the theatre."

> I really keen to know whether I can use another conjunction "when" as the  grammar rule in the above sentence.
>
> E.g,"When in Bangkok, you should go to the theatre."

Comment: The can mean the same thing OR: While means ***during the time*** you are in a place; When ***can mean***: If you go to Bangkok.

Answer (score 2):

"While in" is closer to "during the time you are there".

"When in" is closer to "if you happen to be there"